# Graphics2D fillPolygon

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, polygon

I am trying to make a close button in an undecorated JFrame. I have made a [Polygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html)

```
Polygon closePol = new Polygon(
            new int[] {getWidth() - 25, getWidth(), getWidth(), getWidth() - 25}, 
            new int[] {0, 0, 25, 25}, 4);
```

When I do this, `g.fillPolygon(closePol);` nothing happens but when I do this

```
g.fillPolygon(new int[] {getWidth() - 25, getWidth(), getWidth(), getWidth() - 25}, 
              new int[] {0, 0, 25, 25}, 4);` ,
```

I see a polygon. Why isn't the first one working?

Comment: What is the value you're getting out of `getWidth()`? I'm betting it's not 25.

Comment: @MartinCarney It is 500

Comment: A wild guess: It may be that you are *creating* the polygon at a different place than where you are *painting* it. If this is the case, then it could be that when you are *creating* it, the `getWidth()` method still returns 0, because the component is not yet visible. In doubt, post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that `getWidth()` in `closePol` is called outside the scope of the `paintComponent` method, so the current width is is not *yet* taken into account (or may still be zero), which could happen due a a few reasons.

As a general rule, when painting, you will want to call `getWidth()/getHeight()` in the `paint[Component]()` method. For example when expanding the frame, if `getWidth()` is not called with the method, the new width will not be taken into account, and there will be no dynamic resizing of the graphic (if that's what you want.

You will also want to consider overriding `getPreferredSize()` when doing custom painting, as to give the panel some sizing hints.